# How do I vote on a map in CS:GO?

Tags: counter-strike-global-offensive

Is it me being stupid, or do my keys not work while voting on a map in CS:GO?

I press 1 to 8 when the map vote appears at game end, nothing happens, sometimes I jumble keys to manage to get something happen, and a map gets really voted on, but then I don't know if I did it and how I did it.

Can somebody point me in the right direction?

Comment: I could be wrong, but I think you vote with the F1 - F12 keys. Or was it via open chat > type number > enter ?

Comment: I'll try the chat thing next time, but I'm pretty sure that Function keys don't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you said,by default you should be able to vote maps with number keys(1-8).

In game those keys are used to select your weapons,and as such can be binded to other keys.

So if you change the number 1(primary weapon) to lets say letter K...If you wanted to vote for the first map you will have to press K,pressing 1 wouldn't give your vote.

This is the default binding,if you want to vote maps with numbers 1-8 you should bind it correspondingly.

[image]

Comment: nope, weapons are not bound to any of those keys. Was the first thing I checked.

Comment: That is the problem then,your weapons should be bound to those keys if you want to vote with numbers.

Comment: Hmm, those actions are bound to the mouse buttons and scroll wheel. Is there any chance to solve this without unbinding them from my mouse?

Comment: well you can still vote with those buttons as  they are,you just have to figure out which of those muse buttons represents which number

Comment: As suspected, I could vote with my mouse buttons. I wish it were possible to vote with dedicated keys :_(